# How to implement geo location based push notifications on iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, geolocation, apple-push-notifications

How to implement geo location based push notifications ? please help me

but i have solution is [How to use geo-based push notifications on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590655/how-to-use-geo-based-push-notifications-on-ios)

in this method there are given local based notification

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.alertBody = locationData;
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Location data received";
    localNotification.hasAction = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
```

but how to implement geo location  for example: user enter into some area then the notification want to release

please help me with code or procedure to do this..

Comment: If you're looking for an easy solution, you could check out Proximi.io [link](http://proximi.io). It's a free platform for geofencing, also for iOS. Simple to use, just draw the areas and add the messages you want to push.

Comment: I have the same question. But, why there is no one else answer it?