# How to implement Push Notification Based on Geo Location in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, geolocation, apple-push-notifications

How to implement geo location based push notifications ?   I have been referred to the following solution: [How to use geo-based push notifications on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590655/how-to-use-geo-based-push-notifications-on-ios)

In the above link they have given local notification based solution:

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 localNotification.alertBody = locationData;
 localNotification.alertAction = @"Location data received";
 localNotification.hasAction = YES;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
```

But how to implement it for geo location?
for example: if user enters some area then push notification via `apns`

Comment: Geographic-based notifications are local notifications, they are not linked to push (remote) notifications, and do not use APNS. Push notifications come from a server, while geographic-based notifications are triggered locally by the phone knowing it's own position. If you want your server to be aware of the location, you need to implement background location updates and send the data to your server yourself, there is no standard API for this.

Comment: @jcaron i.e, i have to update user location ,based on updated location i have to send push notification