# Update user's location in background (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cllocationmanager

I'm building an app that takes the user's location and checks if he's near one of his friend's house (all the friends addresses are stored in NSMutableArray from his contact list), if he is, it sends him a push notification.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how I can get the user's location when the app is in the background (and even after the user killed the app from the multitasking screen).

I need to analyze his location and check if he is near one of the addresses on the array.

Does anybody know how can I get the location? Thanks!

Comment: write your background updation code in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {} method.

Comment: @iosdeveloper But this method is being called just one time, doesn't it? I want to update the location every time the user moves

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492420/how-to-implement-push-notification-based-on-geo-location-in-objective-c

Comment: this will not call only one time.whenever your app goes to background i will call.and for every time you have to start timer (NSTimer) in (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {} method.

Comment: @Yhper our problem is solved..

Comment: @iOSDeveloper I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: Please review this answer
It may helps you..
[Get Location in every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465280/8061359)