# Compare user's location in background

Tags: location, uialertview, background-process, battery

I have an application which allows users to make bookings for a class in a particular time slot. I am supposed to capture the current location of user and check if he has been near the booked class at the time slot in which he had made the booking and alert him to rate the class at the same time. Can someone let me know how to proceed with this scenario. Do I need to continuously capture the location and check if it matches with the location of the booked class. What do I do if the user has closed the app? Should I capture the location in background. How do I compare it with the desired location when the app is in background. Also there will be an effect on the battery if I continuously capture the location. Can It lead to rejection of my app from Apple too?I'm bit of a newbie so any help in this matter will be appreciated. Have checked couple of links too like [Update user's location in background (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653129/update-users-location-in-background-ios) and [How to track user location in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465929/how-to-track-user-location-in-background) but haven't found satisfactory answers.

Comment: Sounds like a longer term class project  Most of it is pretty straight forward to investigate so I'll leave it to  you to learn. If you're not familiar with getting location data, check out the google location RESTful APIs.

Comment: I've come across Geo Fencing as a possible solution. It seems useful as I can capture the location of user automatically when he enters or exits a region registered as a geo-fence. This will work even in the background or if the app is killed right. Please correct me if I am wrong. My only concern is that will this continuous location monitoring lead to app  rejection by Apple?